# Is $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})^*$ separable? If so, why?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

I have reason to believe that the dual of $\ell^1$ is separable but I cannot prove it easily since $\ell^1$ is not reflexive. I have also tried searching around but have not had any success. If anyone would be able to shed a light on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: My reasons for believing this fact, ehm, were due to a misreading. Should I remove the question? Also because the answer, perhaps, is trivial?

Comment: It has received an answer, so I think you can leave it be.

Comment: Alright, I agree. Man I feel like I am stacking up a repertoire of stupid questions on this site haha. Need to be more thoughtful before I post my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subset\Bbb N$ define $f_A\in\ell_\infty=(\ell_1)^*$ by $$f_A=\chi_A.$$What is $||f_A-f_B||_\infty$ if $A\ne B$? How many subsets does $\Bbb N$ have?

**Revised** version of the same answer, not assuming we know the dual is $\ell_\infty$: if $A\subset\Bbb N$ define $\lambda_A\in(\ell_1)^*$ by $$\lambda_A x=\sum_{j\in A}x_j.$$What is $||\lambda_A-\lambda_B||$ if $A\ne B$? How many subsets does $\Bbb N$ have?

**Details:** First, the answer is that $||\lambda_A-\lambda_B||=1$ if $A\ne B$. Because if $C=A\setminus B$ and $D=B\setminus A$ then $$\lambda_A x-\lambda_Bx =\sum_{j\in C}x_j-\sum_{j\in D}x_j;$$since $C\cap D=\emptyset$ this shows that $|\lambda_A x-\lambda_Bx|\le\sum|x_j|=||x||$, so $||\lambda_A-\lambda_B||\le 1$. On the other hand, say $k$ is in one of $A$ or $B$ but not the other. Let $x_j=1$ if $j=k$, $0$ if $j\ne k$. Then $|\lambda_A x-\lambda_B x|=1=||x||$, so $||\lambda_A-\lambda_B||\ge1$.

Hence if $A\ne B$ then $B(\lambda_A,1/2)\cap  B(\lambda_B,1/2)=\emptyset$, because if not then if $\lambda$ is in the intersection the triangle inequality shows that $||\lambda_A-\lambda_B||\le||\lambda_A-\lambda||+||\lambda-\lambda_B||<1/2+1/2=2/2=1$.

So $(B(\lambda_A,1/2))_{A\subset\Bbb N}$ is an uncountable family of disjoint nonempty open sets. It follows that any dense set is uncountable:
Say $D$ is dense. The definition of the word "dense" shows that for  every $A\subset\Bbb N$ there exists $x_A\in D$ such that $x_A\in B(\lambda_A,1/2)$. Since the $B(\lambda_A,1/2)$ are disjoint we must have $x_A\ne x_B$ for $A\ne B$. So $A\mapsto x_A$ is an *injective* mapping from the power set of $\Bbb N$ to $D$, and since the power set of $\Bbb N$ is uncountable this shows $D$ is uncountable.

Comment: This depends on already knowing what the dual is, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well yes, but the fact that the dual is what it is is trivial. Actually it depends on knowing just that $\ell_\infty$ is isometrically included in the dual, even more trivial.

Comment: But my guess is that the OP does know that $\ell_\infty$ is not separable. If he already knew that the dual of $\ell_1$ is $\ell_\infty$, his question would be very weird (the natural question would have been «why is $\ell_\infty$ not separable?» in that case, no?)

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with what the supremum norm would mean in this context since I have trouble seeing $\chi_A$ as a sequence, but seeing it as a functional I guess the answer is one. And then this would suggest that it is not separable. Perhaps resting on your second question, which I find myself unable to connect to the problem. If I remember correctly is aleph0?

Comment: @plebmatician Oh dear. No, Cantor's diagonal argument shows that the power set of $\Bbb N$ is uncountable.

Comment: Mr. Álvarez you are correct about my prior knowledge

Comment: My apologies, that is what I meant.. When referring to the one symbol which was the most wrong. Well I guess I could have said finite and that would have been worse

Comment: @plebmatician If you meant $\aleph_1$ that's wrong too, although much less wrong. The power set of $\Bbb N$ is uncountable, but it's impossible  to prove, based on ZFC, that it's this $\aleph$ or that $\aleph$. The connection with the problem: The balls $B(f_A,1/2)$ are pairwise disjoint, hence any dense set must be uncountable.

Comment: I apologise for being slow here, I have seen this argument only once before. I only managed to get the norm of the functional difference to be equal to 2 (by using triangle ineq and then the $\ell^1$-norm). I think for the argument it's not important so long as the radii sum is not greater than 2? Then I arrive at a contradiction at the density, since any functional in the dense set must be arbitrarily close to any other functional in $\ell^1$. But I fail to draw the necessary connection to the countability of the dense set. In my mind there is now no dense set whatsoever..

Comment: @plebmatician See edit - I wrote it all out in excruciating detail. There may be no dense sets in your mind, but there are certainly dense sets in $(\ell_1)^*$, for example $(\ell_1)^*$ is a dense subset of $(\ell_1)^*$.

Comment: Normally I would not write a comment just to express gratitude, but this time I feel it's justified. It is clear to me both the solution and most (if not all) of my misunderstandings. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @plebmatician No problem - I'll send you a bill...